# Use assembly class without the assembly object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, unity-game-engine

I currently load C# code which I have compiled into a DLL using the Assembly class:

```
private void LoadAssembly()
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly loadedAssembly =  Assembly.LoadFrom("E:/MyUtilities/bin/Debug/MyUtilities.dll");


                System.Type type = loadedAssembly.GetType("DLLTest.MyUtilities");

                FieldInfo field = type.GetField("c");               

                Debug.Log(field.GetValue(null));

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log( e.ToString() );

            }
        }
```

This is in a Unity game. It works fine. But I want to load the class into the loading application's domain directly. I want to do:

```
Debug.Log(DLLTest.MyUtilities.c)
```

I do not want to use the assembly object each time to access something in the DLL. Is this possible?

Basically like merging the namespaces and classes of the assembly into the application's code base so I can use classes from the assembly like I would any class defined in the application directly.

Comment: If you control the other dll, you can create an interface that your program know about and implement it there. Afterwards you can cast to that interface and use it directly.

Comment: Is there a way to expose an interface from the program exe to the DLLs?