# Expose a class in my unity game to a DLL that is loaded at runtime by the same game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, .net-assembly

I would like to expose some objects and classes for DLL plugins for a Unity 5 game.

The plugins(DLL/.net assemblies) are loaded at runtime later. But these DLLs need to access classes and objects already created by the main game.

I use the Assembly.LoadFrom() method to load the plugins DLLs: [Use assembly class without the assembly object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466027/use-assembly-class-without-the-assembly-object)

Since there does not seem to be any header files in C# as in C++, how do I expose the game program's(.exe) classes to plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reference UnityEngine.dll and your Assembly-CSharp.dll

Whenever the Unity editor compiles C# code, it most often generates one DLL (it generates more if you're using UnityScript, for example) - that DLL is called Assembly-CSharp.dll, and it gets stored in the `Library/ScriptAssemblies` folder of your Project files in the Editor.

Just like any other DLL, you need to reference it. As it uses the Unity API, you'll need to reference UnityEngine.dll too, which can be found in, for example, `c:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/androidplayer/Managed/UnityEngine.dll`

For most platforms, UnityEngine.dll is the same (i.e. the above is using the one which gets compiled into an Android build), so it doesn't matter too much which one you use, however, you *should* use the one for your target platform.

## Platforms this doesn't work for

As a side note, keep in mind that DLL loading doesn't work on a variety of platforms - iOS and WebGL as well known examples (because they don't run .NET IL at all).

## After a build has been made

You'll want to make sure you reference the correct DLL after a build has been made. With a Windows standalone, for example, you'll easily find it again within the built `*-Data` folder. On android, it can be extracted from the APK too.

## In Summary

In general, when you build the game, you'll need to recompile your DLL (referencing the latest `Assembly-CSharp.dll`).

As a side note, you can also precompile your whole codebase into a DLL and use that in your project, but keep in mind that this breaks `#preprocessor directives` so you have to rebuild it when you swap platforms. However, at least you have full control over when that DLL rebuilds (and as a result, when your referencing ones need to).